# how to prevent submiting a form after a second time in angular or how to submit a form only once

Tags: angular, angular-forms

This is the function that submits my form

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.cityName = form.value.city;
    this.weatherService.getCurrentWeather(form.value.city).subscribe((res) => {
      this.searchedLocationData = res;
    });
    this.weatherService.getForecast(form.value.city).subscribe((res: any) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res.list.length; i += 8) {
          this.searchedLocationForecast.push(res.list[i]);
        }
      console.log(this.searchedLocationForecast, "forecast");
    });
  }
```

the problem is that every time i pres enter or submit the form this function get called and the arrays are filled over and over again with data, and also that data overflows my html page

Comment: before push clean the array `this.searchedLocationForecast=[];`for (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add check before submitting logic and group api call like

```
public onSubmit(form: NgForm): void {
    if (this.isSubmitting) {return; }
    this.isSubmiting = true;
    this.cityName = form.value.city;
    combineLatest(
      this.weatherService.getCurrentWeather(this.cityName),
      this.weatherService.getForecast(this.cityName)
      )
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isSubmitting = false)
       )
      .subscribe([getCurrentWeatherRes,getForecastRes])  => {
      // some stuff
       this.searchedLocationData = getCurrentWeatherRes;
       this.searchedLocationForecast.push(getForecastRes.list[i]);
});
}
```

// Then as optional you can also then disable button to prevent submitting. It just improves user experience

```
<button [disabled]="isSubmitting">
```

Comment: thanks it worked just fine, not only it worked but i got to know what combineLatest is thanky you very much sir